# How do I interpret the data read by matplotlib's imread?

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib

How do I interpret data that's read in by matplotlib's `imread` function, when I read a png file?

```
>>> img = mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
>>> img
array([[[ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
    [ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
    [ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
    ...,
    [ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098],
    [ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098],
    [ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098]],

   ...,
   [[ 0.44313726,  0.44313726,  0.44313726],
    [ 0.4509804 ,  0.4509804 ,  0.4509804 ],
    [ 0.4509804 ,  0.4509804 ,  0.4509804 ],
    ...,
    [ 0.44705883,  0.44705883,  0.44705883],
    [ 0.44705883,  0.44705883,  0.44705883],
    [ 0.44313726,  0.44313726,  0.44313726]]], dtype=float32)
```

I know what `[0.40784314, 0.40784314, 0.40784314]` means, but I don't know what the following means:

```
[[ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
    [ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
    [ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
    ...,
    [ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098],
    [ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098],
    [ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098]],
```

Source: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

P.S: I have edited the question to include the original link (from where it was copied), which may help in answering the question and also, this is somewhat irrelevant to post a link in StackOverflow, still did not flag since I am not sure it is irrelevant or not.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that you understand that `[0.40784314, 0.40784314, 0.40784314]` is a color, but you don't know what datatype the whole image is stored as, and how to use it. It looks to me like it's a numpy `ndarray`. [This](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html) should help you understand more.

Comment: The following subset is the first `row` of the image. Encoded in ndarray (2D) the first array is the row and subsequent arrays are pixel values for each pixel on the row encoded in float32

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imread spits out an array of arrays of arrays. A list of rows, a list of pixels in each row, and a list denoting the color of each pixel.

This is just 1 row of pixels in the image. The results are truncated in the middle, so you only see the first and last 3 pixels of the row when you print it out like that.

```
[[ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
[ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
[ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
...,
[ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098],
[ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098],
[ 0.42745098,  0.42745098,  0.42745098]],
```